# JS: one function and two Document.getElementById() with the same results in "undefined"

Tags: javascript, html, json, function, tags

In my JS file I have a function where I use two variables, choice and courseChosen. The latter needs to be converted to an object first. My html tags are courseName and courseInfo for choice and courseChosen, respectively. These share the this.value is shared by both (they're are supposed to return the same "value"), and this.value also refers to one id (id=course) in the html file.

The Document.getElementById() that refers to courseChosen returns "undefined" as a value whilst the other returns what's expected/selected.

HTML:
(...)

```
\<div\>

\<select id="course" multiple size="3" onchange="choiceMade(this.value);"\>
\<select id="course" multiple size="3" onchange="choiceMade(this.value);"\> 
\<option value="" selected\>--Choose--\</option\>
\<option value="angular"\>Angular\</option\>
\<option value="reactjs"\>React\</option\>
\<option value="vuejs"\>Vue\</option\>
\<option value="JavaScript"\>JavaScript\</option\>
\<option value="Python"\>Python\</option\>

</select>

</div>


<div> <p>
<div id="courseInfo"> </div>
</p></div>

<div id="favorites">
<div>
<label class="standoutLabel">Favorite Instructor:</label>
</div>

<div>
<label class="standoutLabel">Favorite Instructor:</label>
<input type="text" id="courseName" pattern="[A-Za-z]{1,}[+]{0,2}">
</div>
```

(...)

JS:

(...)

```
var instructor = "Axle Barr";

class Course {
     constructor(courseName, instructor) {
          this.courseName = courseName;
          this.instructor = instructor;
      };
      about() {
          return this.courseName + " is being taught by " + this.instructor;
      }
 };  


function choiceMade(choice, courseChosen) {

document.getElementById("courseName").value = choice;   

currentCourse = new Course(courseChosen, instructor); //object

document.getElementById("courseInfo").innerHTML = currentCourse.about();
```

[image: undefined result]

Comment: `choiceMade(choice, courseChosen)` <-- two arguments and you call it with one? `onchange="choiceMade(this.value);"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

everything is right expect the functions declaration. You can replace the function choiceMade as below -

```
function choiceMade(choice) {

document.getElementById("courseName").value = choice;   

currentCourse = new Course(choice, instructor); //object

document.getElementById("courseInfo").innerHTML = currentCourse.about();
```

Comment: Thank you! That solved the problem!!!! Can you please explain what was wrong with my thought process? If I were to comment out 

// document.getElementById("courseName").value = choice;   

to just instantiate the Course class, then I would use courseChosen as the argument:

function choiceMade(courseChosen) {
        
        currentCourse = new Course(courseChosen, instructor); //object
 
 document.getElementById("courseInfo").innerHTML = currentCourse.about(); }

So, why how does declarating with "choice" the function choiceMade() work for both "courseInfo" and "courseName"?

Comment: Hi @Beatriz E , Please look into the function declaration again posted by you. You have two argument seperated by ',' . I think the comma placed by mistake and you just passed one parameter while calling the function that's why course chosen parameter was set to undefined. Thanks